# Python - Writing a 2D array to particular lines in a file (space delimited, no brackets)

Tags: python, formatting

I'm fairly new to python.  Basically, I'm trying to insert a 2D array of numbers to an input file to create a new output file.

Input data is formatted like this:

```
!TITLE
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Really, I am only trying to replace a particular column with a 3x1 array, say:

```
print(newcol_3)
```

Which gives me:

```
[[1111]
 [1111]
 [1111]]
```

My code:

```
Inp_ptr = file('inp_file.dat', 'r')
Inp_data = Inp_ptr.readlines()

firstline = 1
for i in range(firstline,firstline+2):
  old_inp[i-firstline] = array(Inp_data[i].split()[0:12])

new_inp = zeros([3,12])
for i in range(0,2):
  new_inp[i] = [old_inp[i,0], old_inp[i,1], float(newcol_3[i]), old_inp[i,3], ... old_inp[1,11]]
```

Which gives me my 3x12 array.  To print it to the file I've tried:

```
Out_ptr = file('out_file.dat', 'w')
Out_data = Inp_data

row0 = str(new_inp[0])
row1 = str(new_inp[1])
row2 = str(new_inp[2])

Out_data[firstline] = row0
Out_data[firstline+1] = row1
Out_data[firstline+2] = row2

for line in Out_data:
  Out_ptr.write(line)
```

This gets me sort of close, but the input still comes out in arrays (and on multiple lines), so the out put looks like:

```
!TITLE
[  0000      0000      1111      0000      0000      0000
   0000      0000      0000      0000      0000      0000][  0000      0000      1111      0000      0000     0000
   0000      0000      0000      0000      0000      0000][  0000      0000      1111      0000      0000     0000
   0000      0000      0000      0000      0000      0000]
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
!TITLE
0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I'm pretty lost here, I've scoured the web and tried various combinations of ' '.join and \n %, etc.  I'm also sure there's a much easier way of creating the new data set (I understand for loops so I stuck with what I knew).  But I'm open to all suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you `print` a list you get the brackets that represent it.  What you actually want to end up in your file are strings, which is best handled by using `Out_ptr.write(''.join(line))`.

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately got the same result, with the brackets :(

Comment: Then you have nested lists, or something to that effect that I missed ... perhaps `''.join(line[0])`?  Let me run a few tests.

Answer (score 1):

if your use case is really this simple, you can do that like this:

```
with open('inputfile') as fin,open('outputfile','w') as fout:
    fout.write(next(fin))  #write first line directly to fout
    for line in fin:
        ll = line.split()
        ll[2] = '1111'
        fout.write(' '.join(ll)+'\n')
```

Comment: Unfortunately my case isn't that simple.  My actual columns are 10 lines long (and the inut file is 500 lines or so).  The numbers in (newcol_3) are generated using an equation from existing file data.  I just put in this example for simplicity.